# Flutter Project Failed To Compile With Compiler message: Error: The non-ASCII space character U+00A0 can only be used in strings and comments

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-desktop

[image: Debug console image]

Every time I attempt to save and launch the app I encounter this compiler message. I don't know what it refers to and it doesn't show up in my debug console in the problems tab/menu.

Answer (score 1):

Delete and replace any spaces before `data`. U+00A0 is a unicode character 'NO-BREAK SPACE'. You might have copied it into your code somehow.

Comment: I don't see the spaces before data

Comment: @AlraziBashir select a `normal space` and press Ctrl+Shift+L and you will see the non-break space as not selected or **View** | **Render Whitespace**

Comment: @rioV8 I have View | Render Whitespace selected (fyi mac user)

Answer (score 0):

[image: DEBUG CONSOLE [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XkN3.png)

[image: UPDATED MAP STRING]

Turned out to be my Answer widget was calling ['text'] and when ran by Flutter was returning a value of "null" for a Text Widget.